# Запуск слайда по условию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать так если пользователь перешёл по данной ссылке site.ru/index.php#slide1 у него запускался бы сначала слайд номер 2, а потом все остальные

```
 <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slides__item js__slide">
        <a class="slides__item--btn slides__item--position2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slides__item js__slide2">
         <a class="slides__item--btn slides__item--position4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slides__item js__slide3">
        <a class="slides__item--btn slides__item--position" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slides__item js__slide4">
          <a class="slides__item--btn slides__item--position3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test4">4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pauseOnAction: false,
    //animationLoop: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 3500,
    animationSpeed: 600,
    keyboard: false,
    directionNav: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

То что вы хотите сделать называеться перехват якоря. Его можно реализовать так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash != ''){

        // Здесь логика инициализации слайдера так как вы хотели
    }
    else{
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            pauseOnHover: true,
            pauseOnAction: false,
            //animationLoop: false,
            slideshowSpeed: 3500,
            animationSpeed: 600,
            keyboard: false,
            directionNav: false
        });
    }
});
```

Здесь `window.location.hash` это якорь в линке, в вашем случае его значение будет ровно `#slide1` если человек перешел по линку `site.ru/index.php#slide1` и если условие правильное можете инициализировать ваш слайдер по другому.

Answer (score 0):

Решение вашей задачи нашёл здесь, когда изучил api слайдера. Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider